# A sub-mount which is unreachable due to FUSE permissions, disappears when accessed. How?

Tags: permissions, mount, fuse

I tried to contrive a test case using the FUSE filesystem `sshfs`.  My idea was `sshfs` would be a bit easier for developers to test with, compared to the [original issue which involved NFS](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/9835#issuecomment-412115295).  But my idea did not quite work how I expected.

What is happening here?

```
$ mkdir /tmp/alan
$ sudo mkdir /root/mnt
$ sudo sshfs alan@localhost:/tmp/alan /root/mnt
$ mkdir /tmp/alan/mnt
$ sudo mount --bind /root/mnt/mnt /root/mnt/mnt
$ chmod a-rwx /tmp/alan
$ findmnt | grep mnt
  /root/mnt        alan@localhost:/tmp/alan  fuse.sshfs  ...
    /root/mnt/mnt  alan@localhost:/tmp/alan  fuse.sshfs  ...

$ mount -oremount,bind,ro /root/mnt/mnt
mount: /root/mnt/mnt: cannot mount (null) read-only.

$ findmnt | grep mnt
  /root/mnt        alan@localhost:/tmp/alan  fuse.sshfs  ...
```

The sub-mount vanished.

If I re-run this and prefix the `mount -oremount` command with `sudo strace -e trace=mount`, it shows that system call fails with "Permission denied", so that part seemed to be working as expected.

```
mount("none", "/root/mnt/mnt", 0x55b13233d620, MS_MGC_VAL|MS_RDONLY|MS_REMOUNT|MS_BIND, NULL) = -1 EACCESS (Permission denied)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the `mount -oremount` command with `sudo ls /root/mnt/mnt`.  You get the same `EACCESS` ("Permission denied") error, and the mount point still disappears.

`ls /tmp/alan/mnt` would also fail due to `EACCESS`.  Notice that the error will be `EACCESS` even if `/tmp/alan/mnt` had also been removed, or replaced with a non-directory file.

Normally, if `/tmp/alan/mnt` had been removed or replaced with a non-directory, the sub-mount `/root/mnt/mnt` will no longer be valid, and it will be removed automatically.  In this case, when the kernel asks `sshfs` if `/root/mnt/mnt` still exists as a directory, `sshfs` just tells it "Permission denied".  The kernel treats this as a failure, just like "No such file or directory".

I don't know if that's exactly what happens.

Also sub-mounts don't seem to vanish when `ls` on the sub-mount returns `ENOTCONN` "Transport endpoint is not connected".  This error happens when you kill the FUSE process for the parent mount.  (See https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/9872 )